# Checkbox is not showing checked even though the value is 1 from the database

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox(As a cloumn to check if the user is active or not) on a kendo Grid Update Window.It is always shown unchecked  even though its value is 1(which means User is active).If i check when i debug the VAlue is true if the user is Active but the checkbox is not checked. Can anyone help me with the jquery syntax for this.

```
<td>
  <div>
   <label for="Active">Active</label>
  </div>
 <div class="checker" >
   <input id="Z_ACTIVE" type="checkbox" />
</div>
</td>
```

HTML (When i run the code) for one field when its value is 1(Active):

```
<span>
   <input id="Z_ACTIVE" type="checkbox" value="true">
</span>
```

Comment: Is it ASP.NET? If yes where is server's controls. If no, why are you tagging it as asp.net?

Comment: The value  = 1 doesn't tell us anything because checkbox can be checked=true or checked=false. So how should we bind this value=1 to checkbox control?

Comment: Do you know the difference between javaScript, jquery, asp.net and html? If no, maybe then you have to ask about that firstly, and do not ask strange pointless questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input id="Z_ACTIVE" type="checkbox" checked/>
```

Comment: Checkbox should be checked only if its value=true not for all cases

Answer (score 0):

Give below a try:

```
<div class="checker" >
       <input id="Z_ACTIVE" type="checkbox" 
             <% if(DBValue=="1") { %>
               "checked" <% } %> 
      />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged your question with `asp.net`, why aren't you using the Controls provided?

In the .aspx page

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="Z_ACTIVE" runat="server" />
```

And then in code behind

```
        if (yourDBvalue == 1)
        {
            Z_ACTIVE.Checked = true;
        }
```

you write `value is 1 from the database`, but that does not magically set a random checkbox to checked if you don't tell it to.

Comment: Just another question where TS doesn't know what he exactly wants.

Comment: Yep, especially since he answered his own question with something that does not even make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The below Code worked for me

```
       if (Active == "true") {
            $("#Active").find('#Active input').attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
        else {
            $("#Active").find("SPAN:first-child").removeClass("checked");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

In the jQuery, you can have the below line.

$("#Z-ACTIVE").attr("checked", true);

Insert your condition above this line to have the database value checked.

In order to check a checkbox in HTML -

should work as mentioned in the above answers.